# Merge the [gravity-forms-addon] and [gravityforms] tags into [gravity-forms-plugin]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Whilst asking a question relating to Gravity Forms (*a WordPress plugin*), I noticed it had three tags to choose from:

- [gravity-forms-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gravity-forms-addon) tagged to 8 questions.
- [gravityforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gravityforms) tagged to 95 questions.
- [gravity-forms-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gravity-forms-plugin) tagged to 692 questions.

The last one; [gravity-forms-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gravity-forms-plugin) seems to be being actively used and has the most questions against it, but the other two don't have that many, and within the WordPress system, add-ons don't exist, they're called plugins. So it's not technically correct anyway.

This is the first time I requested a tag removal. Should I retag these questions? I'm not sure, but all I know is these extra two tags seem redundant.

Comment: I would suggest the other two tags be set as synonyms of [tag:gravity-forms-plugin] if that ought to be the tag in use rather than burnination

Comment: I've re-tagged the 8 questions with the -addon tag. I can live with the synonym though. If you are going to remove the tag, make sure you fix everything the post, not only remove the tag as the reviewers will gonna hate you for that.