# Time to refile the [form]s

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

While editing a question about an HTML `<form action="POST">` element, I discovered that the form-related tags were not organised very well.

[form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) seems to be a catch-all tag for two conceptually-similar but very different things:

> A form is essentially a container that can be used to hold any amount of any subset of several types of data. HTML forms are used to pass data to a server. VB and C# forms are the windows used to interact with the user.

So [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) is used for both [windows-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms) and [html-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form)s. So far so bad.

Let's tackle Windows Forms first. There exists a tag, [windowsformsintegration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformsintegration), which is *probably* intended for [questions about `System.Windows.Forms.Integration`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/644789/5223757) (this example doesn't have that tag) but is also being used for [integrating Windows Forms into stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46562909/5223757) and [other general Windows Forms questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2487651/5223757). It's a bit of a mess, and not being a domain expert I'm not even sure how useful this tag actually *is*.

I *think* that's all for Windows Forms; it's quite well-kept. Moving on to HTML forms… well, what *should* you tag that `<form action="POST">` question?

- [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post)
- [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [html-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post)
- [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [html-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form) [html-form-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form-post) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) — wait, what?

Apparently [html-form-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form-post) is a thing. 329 questions by normal count, [864 by search count](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[html-form-post]&mixed=0). [485 of which](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml-form-post%5D+-%5Bhtml-form%5D+-%5Bform%5D+-%5Bpost%5D&mixed=0) aren't tagged with [html-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form), [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) or [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post), making them virtually unfindable. Its tag wiki?

> An HTML POST form on a web-page is a set of controls that allows a user to enter data that is sent to a server for processing via an HTTP POST request.

This is a bit of a mess. We need to refile these [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form)s. But what should be done?

Comment: be glad there is no [tag:html-form-get] ...

Comment: @rene Brb, making tag.

Comment: There's [a lot of form tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*forms*%5D&mixed=0) in addition to the ones mentioned in the question

Comment: @Zoe Those all look OK, though.

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen this as burninate request before but I can't find it.

Comment: Presuming the title is [a regional reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_Day)? (For us culturally challenged.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Not really. I just thought "what do you do with forms" and then thought "who has forms" and bureaucracies have lots of forms and they also have filing cabinets… I didn't realise this was something that the US actually did.

Comment: @Lundin Possibly https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366543/burninate-the-gravity-forms-addon-and-gravityforms-tags ?

Answer (score 9):

> So [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) is used for both [windows-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms) and [html-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form)s. So far so bad.

This isn't an issue as such. As long as both of them are *forms*, then fine. An issue would occur, if I create a language called "forms", which has no relation to forms. Forms in general are used to store and submit data. If a question is about windows forms, then it can use the tags, [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) and [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms). There is no issue with that.

Think about the different datastructures. [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) is being used for python lists, C# lists, and even HTML lists. It is not an issue at all, as all of them are related to the exact meaning of "list", which is a collection of items. Take [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) as another example, where it is being used for both Python dataframes and R dataframes, as both of them are about dataframes.

> Moving on to HTML forms… well, what should you tag that  question?

Here is where the trouble actually begins. Till now it was fine. Having multiple HTML form related tags is somewhat useless. The best way here would be just to merge [html-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form) into [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form), and replace [html-form-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form-post) with [form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) and [http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post). (The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) tag, however, is completely ambiguous and must be disambiguated. Related [Retag HTTP verbs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262349/retag-http-verbs))

Comment: This plan seems good! I am learning more about how the tag system works, too, which is a bonus.